# How to resize a 2D nparray with bilinear interpolation?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a (x, y) shape floating numpy array and I want to resize it to (x', y') shape with bilinear interpolation (like cv2.resize image). So any one can help me?

I try to do that:

```
heatmap = np.stack((heatmap,)*3, axis=-1)
heatmap = tf.keras.utils.array_to_img(heatmap)
heatmap = heatmap.resize((img_shape[1], img_shape[0]))
heatmap = tf.keras.utils.img_to_array(heatmap)
```

But I got the 3d int array. Not my expectation

Comment: `stack` joins arrays in a NEW axis.  The first step  makes a (x,y,3) array

Answer (score 0):

Oh I found out how to do this with `skimage.transform.resize`

```
resized_heatmap = skimage.transform.resize(heatmap, (img_shape[1], img_shape[0]), order=1)
```